# Confusion between commands.Bot and discord.Client | Which one should I use?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever you look at YouTube tutorials or code from this website there is a real variation. Some developers use `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` while the others use `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="something", intents=intents)`. Now I know slightly about the difference but I get errors from different places from my code when I use either of them and its confusing. Especially since there has a few changes over the years in `discord.py` it is hard to find the real difference.

I tried sticking to `discord.Client` then I found that there are more features in `commands.Bot`. Then I found errors when using `commands.Bot`.

An example of this is:

When I try to use `commands.Bot`

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">",intents=intents)

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./Cogs"):
      if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"Cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

The above doesnt giveany response from my Cogs and also says

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited  
  client.load_extension(f"Cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`.
```

Then when I try to use `discord.Client`

```
client = discord.Client(command_prefix=">",intents=intents)
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./Cogs"):
      if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"Cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

The above also gives me an error: `Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'Client' object has no attribute 'load_extension'`

***Which one is better in the long run? What is the exact difference?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `commands.Bot` provides a lot more functionality (like `Commands`), which `Client` doesn't do. `Bot` is a *subclass* of `Client`, so **it can do everything that a `Client` can do, but not the other way around**.

In the long run you should use the one that you need. If you want to use `Bot` features then use a `Bot`. If you don't care about `Bot` features then use a `Client`, or you can still use a `Bot` and just not use the extra features.

The first error in your post says `coroutine load_extension was never awaited`, which tells you exactly what the problem is. `load_extension` is a coroutine (an `async` function), and you're not `await`ing it. Extensions were made async in 2.0, and you should adapt your code to that. Migration guide explains what to do: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

The second error in your post appears because you're trying to use a `Bot` feature (extensions) in a `Client`. It's telling you that a `Client` doesn't have `load_extension()`, because it doesn't.

Considering you're using out-of-date code I assume you're following a YouTube tutorial. This is one of the major issues with them. They teach terrible code, and are instantly outdated. They also teach you to do one specific thing, and then you won't be able to create any features of your own. Don't follow YouTube tutorials, just read the docs.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is so much better to understand what your doing which is something I have realized that YouTube videos never allow you to do. I used to "code" discord bots by only using YouTube tutorials and whenever I got stuck like the last couple of days I would just delete the command. When I came back more recently (the last 2 weeks) I tried to not watch YouTube videos as much as possible but I wasn't capable of coding just using the docs. Your answer makes so much sense and thanks.

I'm about to run out of characters so I'll explain the problem with the example in the next commen :)

Comment: When I used `await bot.load_extension(f"Cogs.{filename[:-3]}")` I get another error

| `Exception has occurred: ExtensionFailed
Extension 'Cogs.ReactionRoles' raised an error: TypeError: 'Bot' object is not callable` |

main.py: https://pastebin.com/8wxkM82g

Comment: @DRags that error says that it failed in your **extension**, not in your **main**. Anyways, you're doing `bot()` somewhere in that extension, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: What do I do here then? https://ibb.co/QDLLVcW This is definetely a result of a YouTube video lol

Comment: You remove those brackets. All you want to do is assign an attribute to your cog instance, and the value of that is the parameter "bot". `bot` is _already_ an instance of `commands.Bot`, there's no reason to `call()` it anymore. Just do `self.bot = bot`. I doubt this is the result of a YT video because this just isn't functional Python-wise and it wouldn't work in a video either. This isn't really about the library, it's just Python.